# Is apostrophe is to be put or not: "it will be sent to your address as an official representative'(?)s"?

Tags: apostrophe

I was writing an e-mail and stuck on this part:

> "...a certificate will be sent to your address as the local representative’s."

I have doubts about the apostrophe. Actually I did sent e-mail without it, now I'm worrying I should have put apostrophe.

Please give share your knowledge: to apostrophe or not to apostrophe?

Comment: "sent to your address as the local representative’s" = "sent to your address as being that of the local representative".

Comment: As @EdwinAshworth said.  I think you're trying to write a more formal version of "Since you are the local representative, a certificate will be sent to your address".  Is that the sense?

Answer (score 1):

Is there one representative or are there several? In either case I see no need for any apostrophe.

If it is a singular person:

> ...a certificate will be sent to your address as the local representative.

If there are more than one person:

> ...a certificate will be sent to your address as the local representatives.

There is no possessive form needed and hence no need for an apostrope.

Comment: It depends on what Mary is trying to say ... but yeah, best guess from context is that there is no need for the apostrophe.